# Cast int* to string and then string to int*

Tags: c++, casting

In my game I have people with random names, names that are stored in a string**

```
string          **name_tabs()
{
  string        **names_tab;
  int           *max_0; *max_0 = 8; //girls number
  int           *max_1; *max_1 = 8; //boys number

  names_tab = new string*[3];

  names_tab[0] = new string[8]; //index 0 for girls_names_tab
  names_tab[1] = new string[8]; //index 1 for boys_names_tab
  names_tab[2] = new string[2];
  //index 2 for max_index when parsing either boys or girls tab

  names_tab[0][0] = "Fernande";
  names_tab[0][1] = "Gertrude";
  names_tab[0][2] = "Aicha";
  names_tab[0][3] = "Pamella";
  names_tab[0][4] = "Carla";
  names_tab[0][5] = "Simone";
  names_tab[0][6] = "Svetlana";
  names_tab[0][7] = "Carmene";

  names_tab[1][0] = "Ludo";
  names_tab[1][1] = "Luc";
  names_tab[1][2] = "Bruno";
  names_tab[1][3] = "Olivier";
  names_tab[1][4] = "Fabrice";
  names_tab[1][5] = "Hadrien";
  names_tab[1][6] = "Hazizoul";
  names_tab[1][7] = "DK";

  names_tab[2][0] = reinterpret_cast<char*>(max_0);
  //this cast is just a try that seemed to work
  names_tab[2][1] = reinterpret_cast<char*>(max_1);
  //idem

  return (names_tab);
}
```

When I first made this tab, it only was a string*[2] but I didn't want to have troubles later, if I had more boys than girls and vice versa, when trying to access my names, so I wanted to do something like that:

```
_name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % *(names_tab[2][_sex])];
// with _name and _sex members of same class Chose
```

But it does not compile...

```
class/laChose.cpp:51:39: erreur: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
     new_name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % *(names_tab[2][_sex])] + new_name;
```

I tried different casts, none of them worked...

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do or do I have to make a structure for my names_tab ?

```
struct names_tab
{
  string         *names_tab[2];
  int            index_max[2];
};
```

Also, if it is possible, is there a way I can do this (with casts):

```
names_tab[2][0] = 8;

_name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % names_tab[2][_sex]];
```

Looking forward to your answers !

[EDIT]:

Thanks for your help ! There is the solution I chose :

[SOLUTION]:

```
vector<string>          *name_tabs()
{
  vector<string>        *names_tab;

  names_tab = new vector<string>[2];

  names_tab[0].push_back("Fernande");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Gertrude");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Aicha");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Pamella");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Carla");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Simone");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Svetlana");
  names_tab[0].push_back("Carmene");

  names_tab[1].push_back("Ludo");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Luc");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Bruno");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Olivier");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Fabrice");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Hadrien");
  names_tab[1].push_back("Hazizoul");
  names_tab[1].push_back("DK");

  return (names_tab);
}



_name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % names_tab[_sex].size()]
```

Comment: why not have two [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), one for female names, and one for male names ?

Comment: Skip all those pointers and raw arrays, these aren't necessary with c++.  They'll only provide more harm than good.

Comment: Also you can't cast incompatible types directly. You need `std::to_string()` and `std::stoi()` for example.

Comment: Because I don't know much about std::vector and thought an array would work :x (and don't know yet how to use it)

Oh I think I see, I go have a look to std::stoi() thanks

Comment: @HadrienDaures So go read up on `std::vector`, it will make this so much easier. C style arrays and pointers make everything ten times more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Ok Thanks SanderDeDyker and Lundin, vector<string>* worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::string does neither have operator* nor has an auto conversion to char*. You must use an explicit conversion to const char*, called c_str():

```
    _name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % *(names_tab[2][_sex].c_str()];
```

Although this is still hacking, your structure solution is a more proper way. Even more proper is to use std::vector instead of arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks, your solution solved the problem but I tried to use a vector<string>*, worked well !

Answer (score 2):

Especially when you are learning, you should prefer `std::vector`, or `std::array<>` over C-arrays:

```
constexpr std::array<std::vector<std::string>, 2> name_tabs() {
  return {{"Fernande"s, "Gertrude"s, "Aicha"s,
           "Pamella"s,  "Carla"s,    "Simone"s,
           "Svetlana"s, "Carmene"s},
          {"Ludo"s,     "Luc"s,      "Bruno"s,
           "Olivier"s,  "Fabrice"s,  "Hadrien"s,
           "Hazizoul"s, "DK"s}};
}
```

This code is untested, you might have to add typenames to the Initializations.

If you have more boys, or more girls, just add their names to the list. `std::vector` will take care of the sizes and the memory management. With that you should be able to do something like this:

```
_name = names_tab[_sex][rand() % names_tab[_sex].size()];
```

Though I think, you should have a look at the more flexible [C++ random library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random), instead of the old C-function `rand()`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I'm going to try it too !

Answer (score 1):

You can store a list of names in a vector of string, spelled `std::vector<std::string>`, and then generate a random number between 0 and 7 and use that as an index to your vector to display a random name...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> m_vec = {"Fernande", "Gertrude", "Aicha", "Pamella", "Carla", "Simone", "Svetlana", "Carmene"};
    vector<string> f_vec = {"Ludo", "Luc", "Bruno", "Olivier", "Fabrice", "Hadrien", "Hazizoul", "DK"};

    srand(time(0)); // ensure truly randomized number   

    int x = rand() % 8; // find random number between 0 and 7

    cout << "Random boy's name: " << m_vec[x] << endl;
    x = rand() % 8;
    cout << "Random girl's name: " << f_vec[x] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I could have done it that way but I really wanted to have once for all the assignements done to one variable so I can use it in a loop without having to de the assignemet everytime, but thanks anyway for this solution !